# Multiplication of diagonal and invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Say that $A$ is a square invertible matrix and $N$ is a non-diagonal matrix? Is $ANA^{-1}$ also a non-diagonal matrix? Suppose that $N$ is a non-diagonal nilpotent operator such that $N^m = 0$. Then is $e^{N} = \sum_{j=0}^{m} \frac{N^{j}}{j!}$ a non-diagonal matrix?`

Comment: You have two distinct, unrelated questions in this post.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, can you answer either of them?

Comment: Probably, you should separate these questions into two posts. First one is easier to answer than the second one. Let $N$ be diagonalizable and $A$ be the matrix of its eigenvectors, then $ANA^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $N$ as entries.

Comment: The answer to the first question is no, the answer to the second one is yes.

Comment: Why is the second question true?

Comment: You can find $A$ such that $ANA^{-1}$ is in Jordan normal form. Then $Ae^NA^{-1}$ is non diagonal upper unitriangular, hence is not diagonalizable. Thus $e^N$ is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Take $N=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

---

If $N$ is nilpotent, then there is $A$ invertible, such that $M=ANA^{-1}$ has zeros everywhere except for some $1$s right on top of the main diagonal. Then $e^N=A^{-1}e^MA$. Observe that $e^M$ has non-zero entries only strictly above the main diagonal and has diagonal $1$ all along. Therefore, its only eigenvalue is $1$. However, its corresponding eigenspace doesn't have full dimension, unless $e^M-I=0$, which happens only if $M=0$ (Observe how powers of $M$ have the $1$s shifted further up to a higher diagonal). Therefore, $e^N$ is only diagonal if and only if $N=0$. This is excluded by the condition that $N$ is asked to be non-diagonal.